# Are "produces" and "consumes" attributes necessary for a Spring Boot Rest Service?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm developing REST service using Spring Boot. If I use a response entity, my model object is by default resulting in JSON.

In this case, do I need to specify `consumes` and `produces` attributes in each of the services?

Comment: No, the default ones are json.

Comment: Such a shame that the docs are silent about the default behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-custom-web-predicate-consumes):

**Consumes**

> For a `@WriteOperation` (HTTP `POST`) that uses the request body, the consumes clause of the predicate is `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/json`. For all other operations the consumes clause is empty.

**Produces**

> The produces clause of the predicate can be determined by the produces attribute of the `@DeleteOperation`, `@ReadOperation`, and `@WriteOperation` annotations. The attribute is optional. If it is not used, the produces clause is determined automatically.
>
> If the operation method returns `void` or `Void` the produces clause is empty. If the operation method returns a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`, the produces clause is `application/octet-stream`. For all other operations the produces clause is `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/json`.

So you are producing *JSON* by default unless you are returning a Resource, and then you are producing an *octet-stream* by default.

Comment: The documentation referenced is in the Spring Actuator section (hence the references to application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json). From where do we know that this applies generally to Spring REST? (I am looking, but have yet to find a definitive reference myself).